# Textbox in Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have totally 6 Label box and 6 text box and also 1 gridview where user can enter the detail,so whenever button clicks it stores the gridview value and all the textbox values in DB and generate RequestID(DateFormat).

Is it possible to set a textbox or anyother thing in Gridview so that user can enter.
Below is my gridview

```
Point ID    *East       *North      Height
1                   
2                   
3                   
4
```

The first column should be auto incremented and new row will generate.

Could you please help as I am new to DotNet.

Comment: Wow! Time for your first lession google "Editable gridview in asp.net"

Comment: do some work 
check here
https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=add%20edit%20delete%20gridview%20in%20asp.net

Comment: I donot want to create Edit column in gridview.
User can enter it directly(Not a Editable)